# Java: Adding item to child's list from parent's constructor

Tags: java

I have a abstract class with an abstract list getter/setter that must be implemented by its childs. How do I add item to child class calling getter from parent?

Here is my sample code:

1) Abstract Class

```
    import java.util.List;

    public abstract class AbstractParent<T> {

        public abstract List<T> getList();

        public abstract void setList(List<T> list);

        public AbstractParent(T item) {
            getList().add(item);
        }

    }
```

2) Implementation

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Child extends AbstractParent<Item> {

        private List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();

        public Child() {
            super(new Item());
        }

        @Override
        public List<Item> getList() {
            if (this.list == null)
                list = new ArrayList<Item>();
            return this.list;
        }

        @Override
        public void setList(List<Item> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Child c = new Child();
            System.out.println(c.getList().size());
        }

    }
```

3) Item

```
    public class Item {

        public Item() {

        }

    }
```

The output of line System.out.println(c.getList().size()); (#2) is always 0 despite I added an item to list in AbstractParent constructor (#1). Is there anything I missing? Or child object is not ready according to lifecycle?

Comment: You're initilizing the list twice: once when the parent constructor calls getList(), and one when the child constructor is invoked and thus replaces the list with `new ArrayList<Item>();`. Calling overridable methods from the parent constructor is a very bad practice, for exactly the reason you found out: it calls a subclass method on a partially constructed object. Don't do that. Change your design.

Comment: You're right, I missed this second initialization in child's class init. And, I agree it's a bad practice but I have not much choice because what I'm developing is something much more complex and involves generics and JPA entities. 

My main problem is when I generate JPA metamodel it doesn't replace generic type parameter by concrete class on its childs so I can't build strongly typed JPA queries through CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: The best implementation to archieve what I need is to add generic list to abstract parent class. It would be nice if it is not JPA for the reason I explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the double initialization on the Child class;

```
private List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

to

```
private List<Item> list;
```

and the code will work fine.

**Remember that**
The constructor will:

1. Call super().
2. Execute any inline initializations and anonymous
   initialization blocks.
3. Execute the remaining body of the
   constructor.

So when you call the super the inline initialization is not executed yet, so the list is null, then you call getList() and this initialize a list and put the Item in it, after the super is completed, the iniline initialization get executed so a new empty list is created, finally you call getSize() that return 0

As pointed out by @GhostCat in the comment this is a really bad pattern, you should change it by creating an instance of the list directly on the abstract class or passing it in the superconstructor

Comment: It does work, but creating instances within an getter is more of an anti-pattern. JB's comment is spot on: you don't fix this by dropping the double init, you fix this by changing the design.

Comment: Hello, you're right, I missed out initialization on child's constructor. About anti-pattern, actually, there is no initialization within getter in my real scenario, I did it just to do some tests. But you reminded a good point. Thank you!